# Legend with different symbol sizes in base R

Tags: r, size, legend

In my chart I encode some information in the diameter of the circles plotted. My question is, what is the easiest way to document that information in a legend?

Here is what I tried until now:

```
dat <- rnorm(100)
cex_brks <- quantile(dat, c(0.25,0.5,0.75))
cex_size <- c(1,1.4,1.8, 2.2) 
cex <- rep(NA, length(dat))
for (i in 1:3) {
    cex[is.na(cex) & dat<=cex_brks[[i]]] <- cex_size[[i]]
}
cex[is.na(cex)] <- cex_size[[4]]
plot(dat, cex=cex, pch=21)
legend(
    "bottom", 
    legend=c("very small", "small", "large", "very large"), 
    bty="n",
    pch=21,
    cex=cex_size
)
```

However, doing it this way, not only is the symbol (pch) changed in size, but the legend text as well. How can I override this so that only the legend symbols are different sizes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for the `pt.cex` argument to `legend()`.

`cex` controls the size of the text in the legend (as well as providing the *default* values for `pt.cex` and `title.cex`, to be used if they are not otherwise specified).

Comment: Somebody could to the R world a big favor and document all the "cex" variations in one central location.